# Is there a way to get Magic Lantern on my newer model Canon?

Tags: firmware-hacks, magic-lantern

I recently bought a Canon Rebel T6i (750D) and have a short film project coming up soon. I want Magic Lantern on my camera (SD Card) for its fantastic enhanced features, but I am unable to find it from the Magic Lantern website or any other sources.

It would be a great help if someone could post a source where I can download this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The newer your Canon camera model is, the less likely it is that there will be a Magic Lantern build for it (just as with Canon P&S cameras, the less likely it is there will be a CHDK build for it). These things take time to develop. If you **have** to have these features right now, your best bet is to get a hold of one of the models that *is* supported. The newest dRebel model that is currently supported is the 700D (which came out in 2013); your 750D came out this year.  It may take two years or more from the time the camera's introduced.

Understand that *Magic Lantern isn't anybody's job*. It's an open source project developed by volunteers.  For them to develop a build for your camera, they need access to a copy of your camera, and enough volunteers willing and capable of a) downloading the firmware, b) adapting ML's source code for it, c) testing that build, d) and debugging it.  These things can all be relatively scarce, as is the spare time for volunteers to do them.

If you need a build for your camera and it doesn't exist yet, the best thing you can do is to volunteer and contribute to the ML development effort (see: [this thread where someone steps up for the 760D](http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=16052.0)) or donate.

But understand that the ML folks get overwhelmed *all the time* by folks who "need" ML for camera X, don't want to spend a dime, can't code, won't test, and who have no idea of the time, effort, and dedication involved in getting what they want, and who have no intent to help with the process, or any idea just how difficult/impossible the thing they're asking for can be, let alone the internal culture and accepted practices issues of the ML development community (see: [Magic lantern vs. tragic lantern. Any differences?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/100770/magic-lantern-vs-tragic-lantern-any-differences)).

So if you go over to the ML forum to beg someone to make a 750D build—or even just for feature X—understand what you're stepping into.  The communication divide gets very frustrating, on both sides.

To put it simply: if you're not going to be part of the solution, then the only thing you can do is wait and hope someone else steps up and does the work.

Answer (score 5):

Magic Lantern needs to be individually ported to each camera model; if it's not available on the Magic Lantern site, then it's just not available - there isn't going to be another source for it.