# Can Magic Lantern provide AFMA on an EOS 77D?

Tags: canon, dslr, autofocus, magic-lantern

I want to upgrade my Canon DSLR to either an 80D or 77D. The only thing that I find really lacking in the 77D is AFMA, but there is free Magic Lantern software. Can I safely assume, in practical terms, if I ever need to calibrate any lens on a 77D, it's just a matter of installing Magic Lantern?

Comment: @MichaelClark Doesn't specifying the camera model in the title imply that a separate question should be asked for each other camera model, 1100D, 500D, 550D, 600D, 60D, 650D, 700D, EOSM, etc. ?

Comment: By changing a title in that way after the fact, you essentially make an answer that was written in good faith and succinctly answered the specific question asked by the OP into an answer that no longer even really addresses the modified form of the question because you have so significantly changed its meaning. Perhaps you can create another question that covers the more general nature of the question.

Comment: Remember, the whole idea of the SE network is specific answers to specific questions. We are on firmer ground when the answer to the more general question stays the same than when generalizing the question creates many different answers for specific examples within the entire group.

Comment: Is that Adsense for Mobile Applications or Australian Fisheries Management Authority?

Comment: @MichaelClark The original title did not mention specific camera model. Your answer could easily be generalized without need to mention a specific camera model. Even if you don't revise your answer, it doesn't change that the camera model is mentioned in the body of the question, so whether what you wrote answers the question would be unaffected by whether the specific model is mentioned in the title.

Comment: @xiota The OP wants to know if they ever need to use AFMA on a 77D can they  assume that ML will provide that functionality on the 77D.

Comment: @MichaelClark The original title for this question was **"Magic Lantern as a solution to missing AFMA"**. You gratuitously added EOS 77D to the title to make the question conform better to your answer when **you do not address AFMA at all.**

Comment: I added 77D *and a question mark* to the title to make it a question that matches the *actual question* included in the original body of the question. *"Can I safely assume that in practical terms if I ever need to calibrate any lens in 77D it's just a matter of installing Magic Lantern?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I safely assume that in practical terms if I ever need to calibrate any lens it's just a matter of installing Magic Lantern?

No. There is no stable version of [Magic Lantern](https://builds.magiclantern.fm/) currently available for the EOS 77D. There is neither a "Main Build" nor a "Port in Progress" for the 77D. If or when one will be available is anyone's guess.

Each camera model requires its own version of ML. Sometimes even different firmware versions of the same camera model requires slightly different versions of ML, or there is a version available for a previous firmware version but not the latest firmware version of a specific camera.

Comment: There's no need to include information regarding the 80D since it already has AFMA capability. The crux of the question is can the 77D do AFMA using Magic Lantern?

Comment: The answer doesn't need to address whether ML will enable AFMA on the 77D because the first assumption in the question, that ML is compatible with the 77D *at ALL* is false. If ML can't be used on the 77D , ML obviously can't add *any* capability to the 77D.

Comment: The original title of the question was **Magic Lantern as a solution to missing AFMA**. OP is clearly concerned about AFMA.

Comment: OP also clearly thinks that ML can currently be used with the 77D. Once that false assumption is laid to rest, there's no need to go any further. The original *body* of the question, which is where the OP actually *asks a question* makes it clear the OP is *only* interested in ML as a possible means to enabling AFMA with the 77D. This answer clearly and succinctly informs the OP that is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

No. Not only has porting only just begun for the 77D or 80D (i.e., they're still a ways away from having released versions of Magic Lantern that will work for them) Magic Lantern cannot intercept or affect the lens/camera communication, and as autofocus microadjustment (AFMA) settings are custom functions, and therefore are differently defined for every camera body model, (AFMA) cannot be added to any Canon camera via Magic Lantern.

See also:

- [Magic Lantern messageboard thread on why AFMA on the 60D is not possible](https://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=3540.0)
- [Is there a way to get Magic Lantern on my newer model Canon dSLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71329/is-there-a-way-to-get-magic-lantern-on-my-newer-model-canon-dslr)